# Creating a diagonal matrix from from a vector

Tags: functions, matrix, list-manipulation

I try to create a function that create a diagonal matrix in which the diagonal are:

$\qquad 1,a,a^2, \cdots,a^n,1,a,a^2, \cdots,a^n$

Here is my attempt:

```
nth[n_] := DiagonalMatrix[Table[a^{Mod[k, n]}, {k, 0, 2 n - 1}]];
```

For some reason and I do not know wh,y the diagonal matrix is just one vector. So it seems `DiagonalMatrix` does not work as I expect.

Any idea as to where the mistake is in the function I created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the braces around `Mod`:

```
ClearAll[nth]
nth[n_] := DiagonalMatrix@Table[a^Mod[k, n], {k, 0, 2 n - 1}]

nth[5] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & a & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & a^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & a^3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a^4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a^2 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a^3 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a^4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Alternatively, you can use  [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html):

```
ClearAll[nth2]
nth2[n_] := SparseArray[{k_, k_} :> a^Mod[k, n], {2 n - 1, 2 n - 1}]
nth2[5] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> same result

or use [`Band`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html) in combination with `SparseArray`:

```
ClearAll[nth3]
nth3[n_] := SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> Table[a^Mod[k, n], {k, 0, 2 n - 1}]]

nth2[5] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> same result

Comment: thanks.. it work perfectly.

Comment: which one more practical? I mean later i need to compute power of modified verson of this matrix. so it will be much more computation.

Comment: @henry, `SparseArray` +`Band` is  likely to be the faster than `DiagonalMatrix`.

Comment: final question. If i use MatrixForm as a part of the function. does have any effect of efficiency of the computation?

Comment: @henry, you should use `MatrixForm` is **only** for displaying (MatrixForm acts as a "wrapper", which affects printing, but not evaluation. )

Comment: thanks... this is perfect.

Comment: @kglr I would say that in principle, `DiagonalMatrix` is faster. The crucial detail is to turn the vector into a `SparseArray` first: `DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[a^Range[0, 2 n - 1]]]`

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher,you are right; very good point. If you want to add that form (`DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[a^Mod[Range[0, 2 n - 1], n]]]`) as an answer you have my vote ready.

Comment: Na, I leave it as it is: a side remark. =)